# How to summarize a weighted regression in research paper

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, interpretation, weighted-regression

New here so apologies if I'm not doing this right.

I'm writing up a research paper and my advisor/statistician provided me the following data to report in this paper. He said he completed a variance weighted least squares regression on our data. With all my googling I can't figure out what any of these values mean, and how I would report them so it's understandable in a paper (there's plenty online for more simple statistical tests).

Here's the table I have of the data from the VWLS regression:
[image]

And here's an additional table with the percentages of our outcome for each exposure (BMI) and an analysis of that.
[image]

Please please help, any guidance is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: We can make educated guesses based on what you've shown us, but if you asked your advisor, he could tell you what exactly those show, so why not do it?

Comment: That's fair, I guess I'm hesitant because I'm not sure he knows how it should be reported, he copy/pasted these values from the stata analysis